# Is there a way to create a girdview like asp.net in java frame from jdbc database

Tags: java, asp.net, gridview, jdbc

I am not confident about it, but is there a way to create a gridview kind of thing as seen in asp.net for database work to be implemented in java frames by jdbc..?
If there is way what technique i have to use..I dont wont whole code but just the procedure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to simply bind a JDBC ResultSet to a JTable.  Many examples to do this can be found with Google.

http://www.google.com/search?q=bind+jdbc+resultset+to+swing+jtable